# Mirroring a HTML table with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html-table, jquery-selectors, mirror

I'm trying to mirror a table, with a dynamic grid like 4x4, 7x7, or 9x2.

I dynamically create this:

```
<table id="mainTable" class="mainClassTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr id="row-1">
    <td id="col-1" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
    <td id="col-2" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
    <td id="col-3" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
    <td id="col-4" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row-2">
   <td id="col-1" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
   <td id="col-2" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
   <td id="col-3" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
   <td id="col-4" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row-3">
   <td id="col-1" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
   <td id="col-2" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
   <td id="col-3" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
   <td id="col-4" onclick="imgClick(this)">Stuff Here</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm wondering what would be the best way for each row to get col-1 to move to col-4, and col-2 on col-3. And with uneven columns I fear it would be more complicated.

I found something about shuffling rows, but I want to shuffle columns.

I'm thinking about using jQuery selectors to tediously repositioning each td, but i'm wondering if there might be a nice jquery plugin to rearrange tables.

I don't want draggable, I just want one click to mirror the table (not the contents).

/Edit
So I tried making each col ID unique, but I ended up with this steaming pile of code:

```
function makeGrid(content, rowCount, colCount)
{   
//Empty TD string
tableVarSet = "";
//gridTotal = gridTotal - gridTotal;
//Loop for multiple columns
for (c=1;c<=colCount;c++)
    {
    //make column var
    tableVarSet = tableVarSet + makeColumns(content, c);
    }

//Loop for multiple rows
for (i=1;i<=rowCount;i++)
{
//Make new Row
    rowVarToAdd = "<tr id=TMPR>"+tableVarSet+"</tr>";

    $("#mainTable").append(rowVarToAdd);  
//Set new RowID
    rowName = "row-" + i;
    $("#TMPR").attr('id', rowName);

}
};

function makeColumns(content, count)
{

//Split String
tableVar1 = "<td id=col-"
tableNum = count;
tableVar2 = " onClick='imgClick(";
tableFunction = "this" ;
tableVar3 = ")'>"+content+"</td>";

//Combine Strings:
colVar = tableVar1 + tableNum + tableVar2 + tableFunction + tableVar3;
//Return result
return colVar;
};
```

So, yeah it kind of works but It can probably be a lot easier. (any ideas?)

Comment: I would start with unique IDs

Comment: Perhaps http://www.bramstein.com/projects/column/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using strings, consider DOM manipulation.

```
var rows = document.getElementById("mainTable").rows, cells, fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(var i = 0, len = rows.length; i<len; i++){ //Iterate over each row
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    for(var j = cells.length-1; j>=0; j--) {
        fragment.appendChild(cells[j]); //Remove the cells starting from the end and put them in a document fragment
    }
    rows[i].appendChild(fragment); //Append the fragment's contents to the current row
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VmFK9/) on jsFiddle

Comment: @mplungjan Appending its contents clears it.  jsfiddle wasn't saving when I originally submitted the answer, but I just posted a demo.

Comment: You mean `rows[i].appendChild(fragment);` clears the fragment?

Comment: @mplungjan When `el.appendChild` is called with a fragment as the argument, the children of the fragment are removed and added to `el`.

Answer (score 0):

First you should not be using multiple ID's with the same value!  You should use classes.

Second of all, the below code works but you will need to change it to suit your application.

If you don't want the contents copied just remove the html() call on each of the cells.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="test">
<tr id="row-1"><td class="col-1">col 1</td><td class="col-2">col 2</td><td class="col-3">col 3</td></tr>
<tr id="row-2"><td class="col-1">col 1</td><td class="col-2">col 2</td><td class="col-3">col 3</td></tr>
<tr id="row-3"><td class="col-1">col 1</td><td class="col-2">col 2</td><td class="col-3">col 3</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
<div id="mirror"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var table = $('#test');
var OUTPUT = '<table id="test">';
for (var i = 1; i <= $('#test tr').length; i++){
    OUTPUT += '<tr id="row-' + i + '">';
    OUTPUT += '<td class="col-1">' + $('#row-' + i + " .col-3").html() + '</td>' + "\n";
    OUTPUT += '<td class="col-2">' + $('#row-' + i + " .col-2").html() + '</td>' + "\n";
    OUTPUT += '<td class="col-3">' + $('#row-' + i + " .col-1").html() + '</td>' + "\n";
    OUTPUT += '</tr>';
};
OUTPUT += '</table>';
$('#mirror').html(OUTPUT);


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: -1 The first thing you say is don't use identical `id`s, then you proceed to give an answer that will give the user multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: Dennis the comment clearly states he needs to adjust it to his application, I left it like that so he could see the original table compared to the mirrored one on screen, before you down grade you really should read the code to see what it does!

Comment: Even if I give you that, your answer uses HTML strings instead of the DOM, which is not the preferred way to handle DOM manipulation problems.

Comment: While that is correct dennis he hasn't asked for a DOM only method :)